# React with TypeScript - define defaultProps in stateless function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with TypeScript and I've created stateless function. I've removed useless code from the example for readability.

```
interface CenterBoxProps extends React.Props<CenterBoxProps> {
    minHeight?: number;
}

export const CenterBox = (props: CenterBoxProps) => {
    const minHeight = props.minHeight || 250;
    const style = {
        minHeight: minHeight
    };
    return <div style={style}>Example div</div>;
};
```

Everything is great and this code is working correctly. But there's my question: how can I define `defaultProps` for `CenterBox` component?

As it is mentioned in [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions):

> (...) They are pure functional transforms of their input, with zero
>   boilerplate. However, you may still specify .propTypes and
>   **.defaultProps** by setting them as properties on the function, just as
>   you would set them on an ES6 class. (...)

it should be easy as:

```
CenterBox.defaultProps = {
    minHeight: 250
}
```

But this code generates TSLint error: `error TS2339: Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type '(props: CenterBoxProps) => Element'.`

So again: how can I correctly define `defaultProps` in my above stack (React + TypeScript)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After 2 hours of looking for solution... **it's working**.

If you want to define `defaultProps`, your arrow function should look like:

```
export const CenterBox: React.SFC<CenterBoxProps> = props => {
    (...)
};
```

Then you can define props like:

```
CenterBox.defaultProps = { someProp: true }
```

Note that `React.SFC` is alias for `React.StatelessComponent`.

I hope that this question (and answer) help somebody. Make sure that you have installed newest React typings.

Comment: could you add a more specific example on how you got defaultProps working? thanks :D

Comment: This actually works. Thanks @Jurosh would you mind marking this (your) answer as correct?

Answer (score 27):

I believe a better way than described in the React docs is simply to use Javascript / Typescript default arguments.

There's an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569933/484190 but for convenience, here's an example:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";

interface CompProps {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

const Comp: FC<CompProps> = ({ x = 10, y = 20 }) => {
  return <div>{x}, {y}</div>;
}

export default Comp;
```

This will allow Typescript to know that you don't have to provide the prop, and also that it will never be "undefined" inside your component

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: Unfortunately you won't see those default props in react dev tools..

Comment: @pete otaqui Have you tried this with InferProps and PropTypes? I've looked everywhere and I'm not seeing a way to tell TS that the value isn't undefined

Comment: @OrBachar do you know why it's not possible to see the defaultProps in dev tools? Is there a way to get dev tools to show them?

Answer (score 13):

And here's how it works for stateful functions in case others stumble on this.
The key is declaring **defaultProps** as a static variable.

```
interface IBoxProps extends React.Props<IBoxProps> {
    x?: number;
    y?: number;
    height?: number;
    width?: number;
}

interface IBoxState {
    visible?: boolean;
}

export default class DrawBox extends React.Component<IBoxProps, IBoxState> {
    static defaultProps: IBoxProps;

    constructor(props: IBoxProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    ...
}

DrawBox.defaultProps = {
    x=0;
    y=0;
    height=10;
    weight=10;
};
```

Comment: I know this is a bit late. When I try to inherit the DrawBox class and create a sub class using:

"class SubDrawBox extends DrawBox", 

I get the error DrawBox is not generic. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please try answering my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068412

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question. It is a class component, not a stateless functional component.

Comment: This helped me because I was using Class component. Thank you. As a side note, you can declare `defaultProps` like this: `static defaultProps: Partial<IBoxProps>` in case you don't want to provide a default for every property.

Answer (score 6):

For **Functional Components** as of **React 16.7.0** the 'React.SFC' type is being deprecated in favour of '`React.FC`'.

## Example

```js
type TFuncComp = React.FC<{ text: string }>

const FuncComp: TFuncComp = props => <strong>{props.text}</strong>

FuncComp.defaultProps = { text: 'Empty Text' }
```

[Deprecation Warning in Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L451)

[FC (FunctionalComponent) Type in Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L467)

Answer (score 3):

Typing default props in function component with React.FC can result in false type error:

```
   type Props = {
     required: string,
   } & typeof defaultProps;

   const defaultProps = {
     optDefault: 'optDefault'
   };

   const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => (
     <ul>
       <li>required: {props.required}</li>
       <li>optDefault: {props.optDefault}</li>
     </ul>
   )
   MyComponent.defaultProps = defaultProps;


   ReactDOM.render(
     <div>
       <MyComponent
         required='required'
         optDefault='over written'
       />
       <MyComponent   /* type error  <---- false type error */
         required='required'
       />
     </div>,
     document.getElementById('app')
   );
```

error:

```
[tsserver 2741] Property 'optDefault' is missing in type '{ required: string; }' but required in type '{ optDefault: string; }'. [E]
```

Another solution proposed is to use Javascript's own default function parameters:

```
type Props = {
  required: string,
  optDefault?: string
}

const MyComponent:  React.FC<Props> = ({
  required,
  optDefault='default'
}: Props) => (
  <ul>
    <li>required: {required}</li>
    <li>optDefault: {optDefault}</li>
  </ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <MyComponent
      required='required'
      optDefault='over written'
    />
    <MyComponent
      required='required'
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But the problem with this solution is that if you forgot to provide default, a run time bug will result:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
  required,
  optDefault //='optDefault' //<--- if you forgot to provide default
}: Props) => (
  <ul>
    <li>required: {required}</li>
    <li>optDefault: {optDefault}</li> {/* <-- result in bug */}
  </ul>
)
```

A better solution is not using React.FC at all, simply rely on Typescript type inference:

```
type Props = {
  required: string,
} & typeof defaultProps;

const defaultProps = {
  optDefault: 'optDefault'
};

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <ul>
    <li>required: {props.required}</li>
    <li>optDefault: {props.optDefault}</li>
  </ul>
)
MyComponent.defaultProps = defaultProps


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <MyComponent
      required='required'
      optDefault='over written'
    />
    <MyComponent
      required='required'
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Not using React.FC at all indeed worked better for me, thanks!

Comment: Yup, iam agree with this answer, another problem apeared when trying to used styled-component module to wrap JSX.Element like default Typescript type interface

Answer (score -1):

You can put this inside your component

```
static defaultProps: any;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest for me is to define (partial) defaults in the defaultProps directly:

```
export default class TSError extends React.Component<ITSErrorProps, {}> {
  private static defaultProps: Partial<ITSErrorProps> = {
    fullPage: true,
    controlClick: true,
    doubleClick: true
  };

...

}
```