# How to specify (optional) default props with TypeScript for stateless, functional React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a stateless React component with optional props and defaultProps in Typescript (for a React Native project). This is trivial with vanilla JS, but I'm stumped as to how to achieve it in TypeScript.

With the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

interface TestProps {
    title?: string,
    name?: string
}

const defaultProps: TestProps = {
    title: 'Mr',
    name: 'McGee'
}

const Test = (props = defaultProps) => (
    <Text>
        {props.title} {props.name}
    </Text>
);

export default Test;
```

Calling `<Test title="Sir" name="Lancelot" />` renders "Sir Lancelot" as expected, but `<Test />` results in nothing, when it should output 
"Mr McGee".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about `Test.defaultProps = defaultProps` ?

Comment: As a sidenote: try using `Partial<Props>` for specifying a subset of props

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Here's a similar question with an answer: [React with TypeScript - define defaultProps in stateless function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262047/react-with-typescript-define-defaultprops-in-stateless-function)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

interface TestProps {
    title?: string,
    name?: string
}

const defaultProps: TestProps = {
    title: 'Mr',
    name: 'McGee'
}

const Test: React.SFC<TestProps> = (props) => (
    <Text>
        {props.title} {props.name}
    </Text>
);

Test.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Test;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Recently, SFC was deprecated in favor of FunctionComponent: const Test: React.FunctionComponent<TestProps> = ...

Comment: you can also use React.FC in typescript, rather than React.FunctionComponent

Comment: What if the property is something like `names?: string[]`? Even if I give a default value like this, it's still optional from typescript's view, so I have to write `props.names?.join(',')` rather than `props.names.join(',')`

Comment: will only work if all props are optional

Comment: Hi @Lenin this is not the correct answer as specifying `title` and `name` with `?` lets the user pass `undefined` to those values which should not be case if we have specified the default values to those

Answer (score 116):

I've found the easiest method is to use optional arguments. Note that defaultProps will eventually be [deprecated on functional components](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/107).

Example:

```
interface TestProps {
    title?: string;
    name?: string;
}

const Test = ({title = 'Mr', name = 'McGee'}: TestProps) => {
    return (
        <p>
            {title} {name}
        </p>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes! Part of the beauty of functional components is that you can use all the standard javascript function stuff.

Comment: What if the default value is an array `[]` or object `{}`? They can't be used as dependency of hooks since they are created new every time, and will trigger the hook running

Comment: As far as I know, the code should function the same no matter which default value you put in. Would be great if you can link to code that reproduces the problem you are talking about with [] or {}

Comment: Offical typescript cheatsheet agrees  https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/README.md#you-may-not-need-defaultprops

Comment: will only work if all props are optional

Comment: @fullStackChris You cannot specify default unless it's optional. But you can specify only part of the parameters as optional. So if as parameters you have {title, name = 'McGee'} then calling <Test title="Mr" /> will output "Mr McGee"

Comment: Hi, is there the eslint rule that will check that all optional props have the default value provided?

Answer (score 21):

Here's how I like to do it:

```
type Props = { foo: Foo } & DefaultProps
type DefaultProps = Partial<typeof defaultProps>
const defaultProps = {
  title: 'Mr',
  name: 'McGee'
}

const Test = (props: Props) => {
  props = {...defaultProps, ...props}
  return (
    <Text>
      {props.title} {props.name}
    </Text>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: That looks great, can you explain the first lines?

Comment: This is the only correct answer which will work when the props are a mix of required and non-required props. All other solutions concern components which have only optional props.

Comment: Is this a typo? Isn't `(props: Props)` supposed to say `(props: TestProps)`?

Comment: It was a type, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Update 2022

For function components, there is indeed a [possible deprecation](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/107) of `defaultProps` field. I don't believe this will happen so soon due to the sheer amount of code already written with it, but a warning being displayed in the console is very likely.

I'm using the solution below, which provides the correct behavior and proper TypeScript validation. It works with mixed defined/undefined properties, and also with properties with/without default values – that is, it covers all cases:

```js
interface Props {
  name: string;
  surname?: string;
  age?: number;
}

const defaultProps = {
  surname: 'Doe',
};

function MyComponent(propsIn: Props) {
  const props = {...defaultProps, ...propsIn};

  return <div>{props.surname}</div>;
}
```

And VSCode autocomplete is spot on:

[image: VSCode autocomplete]

It has been tested with TypeScript 4.7.

Comment: If you use the component like `<MyComponent surname={undefined}>` the default value will be overridden. In contrast to the solution proposed by kDar with optional arguments, where specifying an argument as undefined will still use the default one

Answer (score 1):

Adding my solution to the pot, I think it adds an additional level of readability and elegance onto the existing solutions.

Let's say you have a component `MyComponent` with a mix of required and optional props. We can separate these required and optional props into two interfaces, combining them for the full prop interface of the component, but only using the optional one to set the default props:

```
import * as React from "react";

// Required props
interface IMyComponentRequiredProps {
  title: string;
}

// Optional props
interface IMyComponentOptionalProps {
  color: string;
  fontSize: number;
}

// Combine required and optional props to build the full prop interface
interface IMyComponentProps
  extends IMyComponentRequiredProps,
    IMyComponentOptionalProps {}

// Use the optional prop interface to define the default props
const defaultProps: IMyComponentOptionalProps = {
  color: "red",
  fontSize: 40,
};

// Use the full props within the actual component
const MyComponent = (props: IMyComponentProps) => {
  const { title, color, fontSize } = props;
  return <h1 style={{ color, fontSize }}>{title}</h1>;
};

// Be sure to set the default props
MyComponent.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Still got error "property is missing type" when called MyComponent in another file and not declare color and fontSize inside it. This error will disapear when all props on IMyComponentOptionalProps are optional e.g color?: red, fontSize?: 40

Comment: Here is a codesandbox with this exact component: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-pine-e3u2g this pattern works.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, now i know my problem, default props didn't work well when using styled-component. Type of MyComponent changes that cause error to required all props including declared props.

Comment: Link updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-optional-props-pattern-e3u2g?file=/src/components/MyComponent.tsx

Answer (score 1):

using @rodrigocfd answer i came up with this method,
it's useful in case inheritance is also involved (for instance i needed `className` being available in my components ,and not encapsulate them in div!)

```js
// base.ts
export interface BaseProps {
  className?: string
}

export const basePropsDefault = {
  className: ''
}

export function setDefaultProps<T, P extends BaseProps>(t: T, defaultProps: P): T {
  // @ts-ignore
  t.defaultProps = {...basePropsDefault, ...defaultProps}
  return t
}


// Card.tsx
import {ReactElement} from "react";
import {setDefaultProps, BaseProps} from "../base";

export interface CardProps extends BaseProps {
  children: ReactElement
  internalPadding?: number,
}

const defaults = {
  internalPadding: 2,
} as CardProps

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`shadow-lg container p-${props.internalPadding} ${props.className}`}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default setDefaultProps(Card, defaults)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but passing the a default prop value on the function as the second voted reply says could lead to subtle bugs or over executed useEffects (I don't have enough rep to reply there, so [here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-surf-wyfuy?file=/src/components/UserTodo.js:526-565) a reproducible codesanbox)

Even if it's a really contrived example, and probably in most of the cases just bad component design, I have seen this more than once, even breaking full pages.

Answer (score 0):

as of react version 18.2 the following will do the trick.

Notice `?` sign. The property can either have a value based on the type defined or its value can be undefined.

```
type TestProps {
  title?: string;
  name?: string;
}

export const Test = ({
  title = 'Mr', 
  name = 'McGee'
}: TestProps) => {
  return (
    <p>
      {title} {name}
    </p>
  )
}
```

Usage

```
<Test /> // Mc Gee
<Test title="Sir" name="Lancelot" /> // Sir Lancelot
```

Answer (score -5):

To me, this doesn't *look* like a typescript issue.

**DISCLAIMER:** I have only tried this with typescript.

However, the problem is that props *always* exists (even as an empty object when nothing is passed in). There are 2 workaround for this, though.

The first, unfortunately, kills the super clean curly-brace-less syntax you have, but let's you keep `defaultProps` around.

```
interface TestProps {
    title?: string;
    name?: string;
}

const defaultProps: TestProps = {
    title: 'Mr',
    name: 'McGee'
}

const Test = (passedIn: TestProps) => {
    const props = Object.assign({}, defaultProps, passedIn);
    return (
        <p>
            {props.title} {props.name}
        </p>
    );
}
```

another alternative that might get a little hairy if you have a TON of props, but that lets you keep your original syntax is something like this:

```
const Test = (props: TestProps) => (
    <Text>
        {props.title || 'Mr'} {props.name || 'McGee'}
    </Text>
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you don't have to do Object.assign with passedIn props and defaults - that's what React does automatically.

Comment: Your solution will probably work, but it's wrong. You should use `defaultProps` static property of a stateless component function to define default property values.

Comment: @TomaszKajtoch According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443098/1601882) `defaultProps` are being depreciated in functional components can you suggest a way of doing this without using `defaultProps`?