# defaultProps not working in react native function component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
const CustomComponent = function(props) {
  console.log(props.size)
  return (...)
}

CustomComponent.defaultProps = {
  size: 64,
  ...
}

CustomComponent.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.number,
  ...
}
```

This is my custom component, size is `undefined` when this component is rendered.
I don't understand why default props is not assigned to size props in this component.

Comment: try `const CustomComponent = function({ size = 64 }) {}`

Comment: Yeah, thanks,  it works, but I wanted to understand why `Component.defaultProps` not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443098/2308005