# still getting Eslint error after defining default value of optional propType

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My code previosly was like this:

```js
type TopBarProps = {
  problemPage?: boolean; // Error here
};

function TopBar({ problemPage }: TopBarProps) {
  ...
}
```

Following the kDar's solution (2nd answer) on [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209352/how-to-specify-optional-default-props-with-typescript-for-stateless-functiona):

```js
type TopBarProps = {
  problemPage?: boolean; // Error here
};

function TopBar({ problemPage = false }: TopBarProps) {
  ...
}
```

But I still get Eslint error: `propType "problemPage" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration. eslint(react/require-default-props)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can disable this eslint check by

```js
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
```

Or you can try

```js
TopBar.defaultProps = {
  problemPage: false
}
```

at the end of the component

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could use .defaultProps property on function components.

Comment: no problem, and yes you can